# retrieving information in parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parse-platform

I am able to retrieve information from the current user in Parse, however, I would like to be able to retrieve information from anyone but the current user.

For example, this is how I retrieve and display information about the current user:

```
Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");

angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
```

than in the html I refer to it as such:

```
{{currentUser.get('username')}}
```

I do not want pull information from the current user but another user as determined by their objectID.Hence, my question is how would pull information of lets say a user with objectid 17845

**Update:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ***************************************************
  // NOTE: Replace the following your own keys
  // ***************************************************
  var userID = document.getElementById("txtUserID").value;

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");


var userInfo = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(userInfo);
query.get(userID, {
  success: function(userInfo) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    var score = userInfo.get("Address");


 var message = 'Address: ' + score;
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = message;
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});



});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="AuthApp">


  <div ng-show="currentUser">

  <input name="txtUserIDName" id="txtUserID"  type="text" value="Please enter your user ID">



</div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--======================================================================-->
<!--Custom website css file is linked here-->
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Font Awesome CSS link-->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--=================================================-->
<!--Javascript file linked here-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/personal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Admin Panel</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ***************************************************
  // NOTE: Replace the following your own keys
  // ***************************************************

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.get($scope.userId, {
      success: function(userInfo) {
        // The object was retrieved successfully.
        var address = userInfo.get("Address");
        $scope.address = 'Address: ' + address;
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      }
    });
  };
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-Controller="MainCtrl">
    userId: <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>
    <div>{{address}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look through the javascript SDK docs? There is a whole section for "Users"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.get('17845', {
  success: function(userInfo) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.       
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

Update answer:

Instead of using dom manipulation javascript such as `document.getElementById` and jquery `$(document).ready`, you should use angular databinding. There is no need to use `var userInfo = Parse.Object.extend("User");` as that is already available in Parse.User.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.get($scope.userId, {
      success: function(userInfo) {
        // The object was retrieved successfully.
        var address = userInfo.get("Address");
        $scope.address = 'Address: ' + address;
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Html:

I'm using ng-blur here which will call userIdChanged method on scope when value is changed and textbox has lost focus. You could also have a button and use ng-click.

```
<body ng-Controller="MainCtrl">
    userId: <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>
    <div>{{address}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just have a quick question that relates to that. Is that the objectID value would be taken from the input text field. in the sense that on the web the user enters the objectID, and then on a <h1> or <h2> tag that information gets populated dynamically. In the sense that if I edit the input text and put a different id, the information in h1 gets updated as well. To make this easier for you to udnerstand, I have included an update under the update section of my initial post. It seems to be correct, but no information is being displayed.

Comment: Technically, that's another question. You shouldn't really change the question like that after it's already marked as correct. It would have been better to create a new question. I've updated my answer. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. and yeah I agree it should be a different question. I applied your suggestions, but it feels like something is missing, I have kindly included an update under the update 2 section of my initial post.